# How to get output of a script in a txt file python

Tags: python, shell, logging, subprocess, popen

I am trying to get output of a shell command in a txt file. so far till now i have succeeded getting output of my script this way

```
import subprocess
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,filename='E:\FYP\FYPPP\AMAPT\hola.txt',filemode='w')
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)   
command="sh amapt.sh"
 logging.info(subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).stdout.read())
```

This do displays the output of my script (amapt.sh) as well as stores the output in a txt file too.
But i have to get the output of "sh amapt.sh -s try.apk" and store it in txt file as above. i tried doing it by this way

```
command="sh amapt.sh -s try.apk"
     logging.info(subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).stdout.read())
```

But i am getting this error on running this code

```
tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address

tput: terminal attributes: No such device or address
```

Comment: Does `sh amapt.sh -s try.apk > hola.txt` work on its own? I.e., in a shell without python?

Comment: The amapt.sh script is invoking the `tput` command. It could perhaps fail if the script is not run from a terminal, for example if stdin or stdout are pipes.

Comment: @Elmar peise yes it does work without python. its a bash script and i am trying to make its UI in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)? You can use the `stdout` argument to direct to a filestream.

```
from subprocess import call
command = ['echo','Hello!']
call(command, stdout=open('output.txt','w'))
```

Comment: Dude You a legend ! THANKS ALOT

Comment: Glad I could help! Also useful is `subprocess.check_output`, which is effectively identical to `subprocess.call`, except what is sent to standard output by the call is returned by the function